# Getting 'unresolved supertypes' error with the upgrade to gradle 4.1

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I just upgraded my project to the gradle 4.1 and now I am getting this error:

```
    Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make 
sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng, unresolved supertypes:
 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions, unresolved supertypes:
 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions, unresolved supertypes:
 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition, unresolved supertypes: 
com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest, unresolved supertypes:
 com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class 
com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest, unresolved 
supertypes: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza class
 com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult, unresolved 
supertypes: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza
```

I deleted my `.gradle` cache to see if that would resolve the error. No dice and I am not sure what's going on exactly. It was compiling before the upgrade without issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using firebase and google play service with different version then you will face this problem.